# Adding a BufferedImage to a JPanel on JLayerPane

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, paintcomponent, jlayeredpane

So, I have a JLayeredPane (technically a class subclassing JLayeredPane actually).  On that is a JPanel.  I want to add a BufferedImage to the Jpanel.

```
public class BigMap extends JLayeredPane implements MouseListener
  JPanel mapPanel;
  BufferedImage theMap;
  public BigMap (BufferedImage m){
    theMap = m;
    mapPanel = new JPanel();
    add(mapPanel, 0);
    mapPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 640, 640);
    //other unimportant stuff
    }

  @Overrride
  public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D gmap = (Graphics2D) mapPanel.getGraphics();
    gmap.drawImage(theMap, null, 0, 0);
    //some other stuff which is working just fine
   }
```

The issue is that the BufferedImage isn't displaying.  The JPanel is definately present as I can set its backgroundColour and see it if I wish.  I realise that JLayeredPane doesn't have a layout manager and have had to set the bounds for the JPanel but that shouldn't be an issue for the JPanel itself, surely?  And given that BufferedImage lacks methods to control its size directly I don't see how I'd overcome that if it were.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `mapPanel.getGraphics()` Why do you try to get another `Graphics` object while you already have the `Graphics g` of the method parameter? Anyway, the Graphics you retrieve is probably invalid. As a general rule, don't use `getGraphics` on component's.

Comment: That was simply because I will eventually have other JPanels on the JLayeredPane with their own images on.  It was an attempt to keep things neat - the Graphics of each Panel being responsible for its own contents.  Bad Practice?

Comment: _Panel being responsible for its own contents. Bad Practice_ No, but this is done for you before the code calls `paint/paintComponent`. You should alsmot never need to take care of the Graphics, Swing will provide the appropriate one at the appropriate time. Simply don't call `getGraphics` on any Component, and you should be just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you override the `paintComponent()` method of your layered pane, not the `JPanel`. The `JPanel` will paint itself later, as one of the children of your layered pane, and this will wipe out what you painted.

In general, a `paintComponent()` method should paint into the `Graphics` that was given to it, not into some other component's graphics.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that.  Back to the tutorial I guess.  Thank you very much indeed, accepted and upvoted.

Comment: Works perfectly now with changes made based on your answer.  Thank you again.